# What if the non-Jew to whom I have sold my chometz converts?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, passover, conversion-to-judaism, selling-mechirat-chametz

What would be the net effect if the non-Jewish person to whom I have sold my chometz for Pesach converts to Judaism over Pesach?

Comment: Interesting hypothetically but you realize this is very *very* unlikely to ever happen, right?  If someone is that close to formally converting then he's already living per halacha to the extent he can and he wouldn't buy your chametz, and that's assuming that a beit din would do the conversion at that time with him owning chametz (or at all; do batei din even convene during chol ha'moed?).

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=12999&st=&pgnum=125&hilite=

Comment: Hypothetically perhaps he could sell the Chameitz to another non Jew prior to converting.

Comment: @gershongold do they put something like that in the contract? are they alowed to sell the chametz to whomever they wish?

Comment: Could someone explain why this question is being downvoted? I agree that it is hypothetical but that doesn't seem to be prohibited by the site

Comment: (For the record, I have not voted on the question.)

Comment: @BackseatChazan re: are they allowed... - the chometz is theirs now.  They can eat it or sell it or play basketball with it.  If you don't think of it as really being theirs, just with intent to sell it back, then it is not a legitimate sale.

Comment: @deja Because you have given no reason to suspect this case would be different from a regular Jew who owns chametz on pesach

Answer (score 5):

From various Mishnayot (see below) we see that a Ger's possessions seem to continue to belong to him after he converts.

In that case, the moment your buyer converts, he owns Chametz on Pessach - Chametz from which everybody is now forbidden to derive benefit from - similar to any Chametz a Jew owns on Pessach.

Result: He would not be allowed to sell it back; he would have a Mitzva to burn it ASAP.

---

Mishnayot:

Peah 4:6

> נָכְרִי שֶׁקָּצַר אֶת שָׂדֵהוּ וְאַחַר כָּךְ נִתְגַּיֵּר, פָּטוּר מִן הַלֶּקֶט וּמִן הַשִּׁכְחָה וּמִן הַפֵּאָה‏. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה מְחַיֵּב בְּשִׁכְחָה, שֶׁאֵין הַשִּׁכְחָה אֶלָּא בִשְׁעַת הָעִמּוּר:‏

We see that the crop is his; and his ownership carries over from before his conversion.

Chala 3:6

> גֵּר שֶׁנִּתְגַּיֵּר וְהָיְתָה לוֹ עִסָּה, נַעֲשֵׂית עַד שֶׁלֹּא נִתְגַּיֵּר, פָּטוּר, וּמִשֶּׁנִּתְגַיֵּר, חַיָּב‏. וְאִם סָפֵק, חַיָּב, וְאֵין חַיָּבִין עָלֶיהָ חֹמֶשׁ. רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא אוֹמֵר, הַכֹּל הוֹלֵךְ אַחַר הַקְּרִימָה בַתַּנּוּר :‏

Here it's even clearer that the dough belongs to him even after his conversion.

Chulin 3:10

> :‏גֵּר שֶׁנִּתְגַּיֵּר וְהָיְתָה לוֹ פָרָה, נִשְׁחֲטָה עַד שֶׁלֹּא נִתְגַּיֵּר, פָּטוּר. מִשֶּׁנִּתְגַּיֵּר, חַיָּב. סָפֵק, פָּטוּר

Here again we see that his ownership of the cow continues through his conversion; freeing/obligating him with Matnot Kehuna (זְּרוֹעַ לְּחָיַיִם קֵּבָה ).